# Getting an object from a ComboBox BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I'm working on a school project with C# Winforms where I have to create a vehicle sales invoice and ope a new form with information about the vehicle that was selected from a combobox. How do I get the Vehicle object or its properties based on the SelectedItem in the combobox?

The Vehicle objects are in a list which is bound to a BindingSource which is bound to the combobox.
I was able to pass static strings through to a new form in another component of this assignment, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the object information.

My list of vehicles bound to the combobox. DataRetriever is a class we were given to provide us with the Vehicle objects. They have auto-implemented properties (make, model, id, colour, etc.)

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = DataRetriever.GetVehicles();
            BindingSource vehiclesBindingSource = new BindingSource();
            vehiclesBindingSource.DataSource = vehicles;
            this.cboVehicle.DataSource = vehiclesBindingSource;
            this.cboVehicle.DisplayMember = "stockID";
            this.cboVehicle.ValueMember = "basePrice";
```

I want to be able to pass information to this form and display information about the selected vehicle with labels.

```
private void vehicleInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VehicleInformation vehicleInformation = new VehicleInformation();
            vehicleInformation.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Then pass the object you want to that form.  Best with a custom constructor: `public VehicalInformation(Vehicle vehicle) {...}`

Comment: Or add (to the `VehicleInformation` Form) a public property or method that accepts a `Vehicle` type argument. You can set it before you show it. Or after, as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

1. On `Form_Load`

   ```
   List<VecDetails> lstMasterDetails = new List<VecDetails>();

   private void frmBarcode_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       VechicleDetails();

       BindingSource vehiclesBindingSource = new BindingSource();
       vehiclesBindingSource.DataSource = lstMasterDetails;
       this.comboBox1.DataSource = vehiclesBindingSource;
       this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "stockID";
       this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "basePrice";
   }
   ```
2. In `VechicleDetails()` Method i'm just generating the sample value so i can i them to `ComboBox`

   ```
   private void VechicleDetails()
   {
       //Sample Method to Generate Some value and 
       //load it to List<VecDetails> and then to ComboBox
       for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
       {
           VecDetails ve = new VecDetails();
           ve.stockID = "Stock ID " + (n + 1).ToString();
           ve.basePrice = "Base Price " + (n + 1).ToString();
           lstMasterDetails.Add(ve);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now on `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event i'm getting the value of the item selected

   ```
   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      try
      {
         string strStockId = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
         string strBasePrice = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as dynamic).basePrice;
         label1.Text = strStockId + " - " + strBasePrice;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      }
   }
   ```

[image: Example]

Comment: Since you're using a BindingSource, you could add a Binding to the Label, set to the Text property, the BindingSource, the bound class property and specify `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`. The `SelectedIndexChanged` handler can be removed, since the data change notification is handled by the BindingSource.